# Возможно ли имитировать невозможность подключения к серверу (искусственно вызывать ERR_TIMED_OUT)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, http

У меня есть простяцкий http.server на питоне. Каким образом я могу имитировать невозможность до него достучаться? То есть я специально хочу вызвать ошибку хромиума ERR_TIMED_OUT. Как это сделать имея в наличии интернет я знаю: можно просто попытаться загрузить google.com по 80 порту. Такой же еррор прилетает, если из украины стучаться на яндекс или вк (регионально заблоченные ресурсы). Но суть в том, что у меня есть:

1. мой браузер (на базе хромиума)
2. мой сервер (а запускаться это будет на образе, который доступа в интернет не имеет)
3. есть тестовая страничка

И нужно вот из этих трёх ингридиентов сварить вышеназванный эррор. Я понимаю, что нужно как-то настроить сервер. Но как? Я пытался настроить обработчик GET-запросов таким образом, чтобы при запросе доступа к тестовой странице у меня сервер вызывал time.sleep() и задавал таймаут больше, чем у браузера. Но это не помогло. Прилетает Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE). А это другая ошибка, которая не вызывает у браузера необходимой мне реакции. Что нужно от сервера, чтобы прилетел именно ERR_TIMED_OUT?

Comment: Попробуйте отредактировать файл hosts. Хотя не уверен какую ошибку выдаст в вашем случае. Заблокировать сервер антивирусом еще как вариант.

Comment: Вариант с файлом /etc/hosts выглядит вполне заманчиво, но у меня нет к нему доступа. Его редактировать можно только под рутом, а я работаю от своего юзера (окружение такое и менять его я не смогу).

Comment: Создать виртуальные машины с нужными правами. Можно еще в сервер вставить код time.sleep(60).  Что в какой-то момент вызовет зависание сервера.

Comment: timeout это неприлетевший syn, а не сон без ответа

Comment: @Kers я окружение менять не могу пос воему желанию. Мог бы - мне было бы проще наладить доступ в интернет и идти по известным кейсам

Comment: @eri А как можно сделать, чтобы он "не прилетал"?) Я могу как-то модифицировать do_GET метод для этого? (Использую http.server питоновский)

Comment: сокет в ядре, без рута не грохнешь. с рутом проще всего через iptabes DROP

Comment: останови свой http.server  и попробуй до него достучаться c html страницы

Comment: @AndreyMaslov дык не достучусь же. Я работаю с точки зрения клиента (браузера). между мной и страницей сервак. к странице я стучусь по адресу http://127.0.0.1:8000/test.html. Сервак лежит - я просто получаю ошибку, что сервер не найден.